# ReactJS Accordion For loop Key Undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following function.

```
accordianRecentActivity() {
    let div = [];
    const grouped = this.groupBy(this.state.filtered, date => getDateServiceTab(date.date));
    div.push(<Accordion>)
    
    for (const [key, value] of grouped.entries()) {
        div.push(<div label={key}>{key}</div>)
    }
    div.push(</Accordion>)

    return div;
    
  }
```

I am using this component tutorial to build it out.

https://alligator.io/react/react-accordion-component/

I then get the following...

> Line 152:  'key' is not defined  no-undef
>
> Line 152:  'key' is not defined  no-undef

EDIT

If I do this...

```
    accordianRecentActivity() {
        let div = [];
        const grouped = this.groupBy(this.state.filtered, date => getDateServiceTab(date.date));
//      div.push(<Accordion>)
//      
//      
//      for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(grouped)) {
//          div.push(<div label={key}>{key}</div>)
//      }
//      div.push(</Accordion>)
//      
//
//      return div;
//      
        
        
        for (const [key, value] of grouped.entries()) {
          console.log(key, value);
        }
      }
```

I will get the following in the console.

[image]

**printing out grouped.entries()**

[image]

Comment: Did you mean Object.entries(grouped)?

Comment: Can you validate that `grouped.entries()` is an array of objects or kvp and has a length > 0?

Comment: Yes, if I do a simple console.log(key, value); call inside of that for loop and remove the div.push() i see my items grouped in the console.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky same thing with that.

Comment: @MarkC. pls see my edit.

Comment: maybe if you use `.map()`?

Comment: @BlackHole can you share some code on how to do a map on grouped.entries? check the picture I just added for that is returned.

Comment: `grouped.entries().map((object, key) =>{ console.log("key->",key) })` check it please

Comment: @BlackHole I have done that before, it tells me TypeError: grouped.entries(...).map is not a function